# Golang idiomatic way to remove a blank line from a multi-line string

Tags: string, replace, go

If I have a multi line string like

```
this is a line

this is another line
```

what is the best way to remove the empty line? I could make it work by splitting, iterating, and doing a condition check, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming that you want to have the same string with empty lines removed as an output, I would use regular expressions:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    var s = `line 1
line 2

line 3`

    regex, err := regexp.Compile("\n\n")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    s = regex.ReplaceAllString(s, "\n")

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: If the strings are obtained by iterating a huge slice, which one would you recommend for performance? Regex or iteration?

Comment: I would still recommed regex, though if you want to merge those strings later (say, into a slice) then `string.Split()` and iteration might be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you @REACHUS. Much appreciated.

Comment: I disagree. "If the strings are obtained in a **huge** slice", aka []string. So, in order to apply the regex, you'd need to convert said huge slice to a string consuming both time and memory, only to apply the regex after then and converting the string back to a []string. Actually, a blank line in a []string would be denoted by the *rune* `'\n'` which could be identified by a simple comparison.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg As I have understand it, a single element a `[]string` would contain a string with mutlitple lines. Then, it would make sense to filter out empty lines with a regex. **However**, if a single element of a slice would represent a single line, it would of course be more efficient to iterate over the slice and check if an element is an empty line by comparing it to `'\n'`.

Comment: As I have read it, the string would be constructed from a slice. Well, your comments should make that clear. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Similar to ΔλЛ's answer it can be done with strings.Replace:

> func Replace(s, old, new string, n int) string
>   Replace returns a copy of the string s with the first n non-overlapping instances of old replaced by new. If old is empty, it matches at the beginning of the string and after each UTF-8 sequence, yielding up to k+1 replacements for a k-rune string. If n < 0, there is no limit on the number of replacements.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    var s = `line 1
line 2

line 3`

    s = strings.Replace(s, "\n\n", "\n", -1)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lu5UI74SLo

Comment: This should be the better answer

Comment: This is not removing the first empty line.

Answer (score 1):

The more generic approach would be something like this maybe.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `


    #### 

    ####




    ####


    ####




    `

    fmt.Println(regexp.MustCompile(`[\t\r\n]+`).ReplaceAllString(strings.TrimSpace(s), "\n"))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uWyHfUIDw-o

Answer (score 0):

To improve @syntagma response in order to remove all empty lines:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    var s = `line 1
line 2

line 3`

    regex, _ := regexp.Compile(`\n{2,}`)
    s = regex.ReplaceAllString(s, "\n")

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```