# Remove empty lines when scraping with Go-Colly

Tags: go

I am starting with Go and scraping with Colly. Can somebody help me with removing the empty lines from the output? This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    c.OnHTML("table > tbody", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.Text)
    })
    c.Visit("https://www.olx.pl/elektronika/gdynia/")
}
```

I have tried this: [golang regexp remove all blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032254/golang-regexp-remove-all-blank-lines) 
and this: [Golang idiomatic way to remove a blank line from a multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360080/golang-idiomatic-way-to-remove-a-blank-line-from-a-multi-line-string), probably in wrong way, or maybe I am missing something else.

Comment: Provide the exact text content and your best attempt.

Comment: Your code does not produce any output. Use `fmt.Printf("%q\n", e.Text)` to display everything, including control characters like newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the empty lines were not really empty, scraper just did not print elements which are in the DOM, that's why I was seeing so many gaps between scraped text. The issue was resolved by telling the scraper the child elements' specific locators which I wanted to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try standardize space.

```
func StandardizeSpaces(s string) string {
    return strings.Join(strings.Fields(s), " ")
}

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    c.OnHTML("table > tbody", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(StandardizeSpaces(e.Text))
    })
    c.Visit("https://www.olx.pl/elektronika/gdynia/")
}
```